# Set PGF anchor position in custom pgfshape with pgfkey as string?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys, tikz-shape, anchor

How can I go about using a pgfkey to place an anchor if the key is a string?

Previous answers imply that setting anchors based on keys is possible using numerical keys (like this question on [Creating Tikz anchors based on pgfkey value](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91361/creating-tikz-anchors-based-on-pgfkey-value)) or boolean ("if") keys (like this question on [How to define an anchor with location depending on a parameter](http://pgf-and-tikz.10981.n7.nabble.com/pgfdeclareshape-How-to-define-an-anchor-with-location-depending-on-a-parameter-td4176.html)) but I haven't had any luck finding similar examples which use strings or in modifying these examples to work with strings.

As a simple example, in the *(nonfunctional)* code below I'd like to be able to use the `elevation` key to change the location of the north east anchor *(it's my understanding that the `ifthen` package is [considered obsolete](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13866/why-is-the-ifthen-package-obsolete) but I've used it here because I thought it most clearly conveyed the behavior I was after)*:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz, ifthen}
\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{/tikz/elevation/.initial=low}
\pgfdeclareshape{myLine}{   
    \savedanchor{\anchorA}{
        \pgf@x=3cm
        \ifthenelse{\equal{low}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/elevation}}}
            {\pgf@y=1cm}{}
        \ifthenelse{\equal{medium}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/elevation}}}
            {\pgf@y=3cm}{}
        \ifthenelse{\equal{high}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/elevation}}}
            {\pgf@y=5cm}{}
    }   
    \anchor{center}{\pgfpointorigin}
    \anchor{top right}{\anchorA}
    
    \backgroundpath{
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}
        \pgfpathlineto{\anchorA}
        \pgfusepath{stroke}
    }
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw [help lines, dashed, gray] (0,0) grid (5,5);
        \node [myLine, elevation=value] (L) {};
        \draw [red] (L.top right) circle (0.2cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The resulting (desired) behavior based on keys provided to `\node [myLine, elevation=value]` is shown in the images below.

[image]

Comment: Maybe I am not getting the problem (BTW: welcome!) but it's working here...

Comment: Same here. Maybe the OP didn't replace `value` with `low` / `medium` / `high` in the document body?

Comment: I think you're both right! I have no idea how but in the process of trying to make a "broken" example I appear to have fixed it. I'll close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sample code in fact does do what I wanted it to do. Apparently in the process of trying to create a "broken" answer I solved it.

Thanks to Rmano and frougon for pointing out my oversight.